# What is the meaning of the phrase “t'annoncer” in the following context?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

**"La discrétion n'a pas de prix. Mais après tout, si tu préfères t'annoncer et aller frapper aux portes de la ville, libre à toi."**

---

I suppose that it somewhat departs from the usual usage of the verb “annoncer”. Does it mean “announce your presence (and draw attention)”?

Comment: If you have two different questions, please ask them separately. You may have to refine your criteria for "excellent" dictionary, as that is very subjective and has no real answer (ie you may not agree with me on what constitutes an excellent dictionary).

Comment: It means rather *tell people about your situation* , not  *report your presence* (this is proven by **aller frapper aux portes de la ville** ) . You may like this [dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french). Note that all dictionaries are good :) That's quite off-topic question here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual, more context might help to clarify this excerpt but I understand here *t'annoncer* to mean announcing your presence, i.e. declaring publicly who you are and indeed draw attention before or by knocking to the doors of the city. This latter part is open to speculation depending on whether the person is outside or inside that city.

In the former case, that might mean the narrator advise the person to stay discreet and enter the city unnoticed, without "knocking the door", but let that person decide to act differently and enter the city an ostentatious way should (s)he prefers to.

Answer (score 0):

In this context It means That you announce your presence. You let everyone know you're somewhere. You want to get the attention.